# Pass D3.js data based on ID specified in data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this randomly generated JSON string:

```
let jsonText = '{"data": [{"id": 4,"x": 16.53,"y": 66.19,"phi": 2.4},{"id": 2,"x": 14.09,"y": 13.15,"phi": 0.13},{"id": 9,"x": 58.04,"y": 67.88,"phi": 2.96}]}';
```

It's an object containing information about 3 SVG groups specified by id number. I want to pass data to these group elements based on the ID in the array, for example to `<g id="4">` pass the first coords and angle etc.

All I have now is this function:

```
function on_render_body(jsonfile) {
    //parse the text and save it to object
    let parsedText = JSON.parse(jsonfile);
    //create data array of positions and stuff
    let data = [0];
    parsedText.data.forEach((element, index) => {
        data[index] = new body(element.x, element.y, element.phi);
        data[index].setID(element.id);
    });
    //select all g elements and give them data based on id
    let groups = d3.select("svg")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(data, (d)=>d.id)
      .attr("transform", d => d.setMatrix());
}
```

It creates an array of class `body` objects, which are designed to contain and work with coordinates and ID of the element. Then I want to pass the data array to all the groups in SVG based on their id, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

See a demonstation in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/ngbu8vt6/):

After you enter an element, its data can be retrieved by the datum() function;
You can also assign an attribute to each element and then find it in the DOM:

```
const bodies = container.selectAll('g.body')
  .data(data, ({id}) => id);
  
const entered = bodies.enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('body', true)
  .attr('body-id', ({id}) => id)
...
const body9 = container.select(`[body-id='9']`);
console.log('ID 9: ', body9.datum())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I get the idea of binding data to elements, but I already have elements in my DOM with specific ID. I just want D3 to give them data based on ID specified in the parsed JSON object. So for example, I want to pass the data to <g id="24"> that contain "id": 24 in the JSON object.

Comment: @wondrush The data is already there. If you have an DOM element (ref), you just extract it with d3.select(ref).datum()